# How to test a method is called with Minitest?

Tags: ruby, minitest

```
class Post
  def save
    Mailer.notify!('bla')
    true
  end
end
```

How to test that when `post.save` is called, the `Mailer.notify` method is fired? and with the right arguments.

With RSpec I usually do:

```
expect(Mailer).to receive(:notify!).with('bla')
post.save
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
describe 'Post#save' do
  it "calls Mailer::notify!" do
    mock = MiniTest::Mock.new
    mock.expect(:call, nil, ['bla'])

    Mailer.stub(:notify!, mock) do
      post.save
    end

    mock.verify
  end
end
```

And yes, that is easier and more intuitive in RSpec...

Answer (score 2):

For mocking with minitest I like using Mocha gem https://github.com/freerange/mocha

I will be:

```
Mailer.expects(:notify!).with('bla').at_least_once
```